# MS SQL Server: transforming SCD-2 to SCD-2 with less variables

Tags: sql-server, etl, scd2

I retrieve data from SCD-2 table with many parameters and I need to build my own SCD-2 with only one of them. Therefore, I need to get rid of excessive intervals. Please recommend an algorithm to perform that in the best way.

What I receive from the source table:

[image: what I receive from the source table]

I need to transform it to:

[image: I need to transform it to:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following steps to get the required result. Of course you can do it all in one step with sub-selects or CTEs, but for better traceability I prefere temporary tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #source;
CREATE TABLE #source (key1 integer, value1 integer, row_actual_from date, row_actual_to date);
 
INSERT INTO #source
VALUES
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'),
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-03', '2020-01-05'),
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-06', '2020-01-08'),
(19999923, 11,   '2020-01-09', '2020-01-12'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-01-13', '2020-01-15'),
(19999923, 11,   '2020-01-16', '2020-01-20'),
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-21', '2020-02-02'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-02-03', '2020-02-10'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-02-11', '2020-02-19'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-02-20', '2020-02-25'),
(19999923, 99,   '2020-02-26', '9999-12-31');
```

Step 1: Identify start and end for a single value period.

Note that in LAG/LEAD it is essentally to have a value as NULL replacement (-99 in example) which dosn't match with the possible values in the column.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #step1;
    SELECT
        key1, value1, row_actual_from, row_actual_to
        , period_start = CASE WHEN LAG(value1,  1, -99) OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY row_actual_from) <> value1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        , period_end   = CASE WHEN LEAD(value1, 1, -99) OVER (PARTITION BY key1 ORDER BY row_actual_from) <> value1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    INTO #step1
    FROM #source
    ORDER BY key1, row_actual_from;
```

Step 2: Filter on start/end rows and assign row_actual_to of end to start.

If the period of a value has only one row this row has period_start and period_end set to 1 and therefore the sum is 2. In this case the content of row_acutal_to has already the wanted value.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #step2;
    SELECT
        key1, value1, row_actual_from, row_actual_to, period_start, period_end
      , valid_from = row_actual_from
      , valid_to   = CASE (period_start + period_end)
                     WHEN 1 THEN LEAD(row_actual_to, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY key1, value1 ORDER BY row_actual_from)
                     WHEN 2 THEN row_actual_to ELSE NULL END
    INTO #step2
    FROM #step1
    WHERE (period_start + period_end) > 0
    ORDER BY key1, row_actual_from;
```

Step 3: Filter (adjusted) start row of value period.

```
    SELECT key1, value1, valid_from, valid_to
    FROM   #step2
    WHERE  period_start = 1
    ORDER BY key1, row_actual_from;
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I used your solution and it seemed perfect to me, until i faced a problem with sort of cases, when a certain value appears in "one-row" interval once, and then "comes back" several rows after (to illustrate, i will paste code below). After number of tries to fix the problem, I gave up :P and decided just to remove rows, where (period_start + period_end) =0. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: INSERT INTO #source VALUES
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'),
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-03', '2020-01-05'),
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-06', '2020-01-08'),
(19999923, 11, '2020-01-09', '2020-01-12'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-01-13', '2020-01-15'),
(19999923, 11,   '2020-01-16', '2020-01-20'),
(19999923, 15,   '2020-01-21', '9999-12-31');

Comment: @GrigoryP: Your right, I have overlooked the case of "one-row" row intervall. I will adjust the answer to cover this case as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is obviously complicated by the fact that the same "value" can repeat in multiple groups - so you can't just use straightforward MIN/MAX functions. You could probably code this in a javascript stored proc but I thought I'd try and find a solution in (almost) pure SQL.

The challenge is to try and create a "group" every time the value changes - as then you can do a simple MIN/MAX on the dates within the group. The way I have (hopefully!) solved this is as follows:

1. Create a CTE where a calculated field is set to the next value in a sequence whenever the value of the current row is different from the value in the previous row; where there is no difference then the field is set to null - this is important due to the way the LAG function in the next CTE handles NULLs
2. Create a 2nd CTE where a calculated grouping column is set to last non-null value in the calculated column created in the previous column - using the LAG function set to ignore nulls
3. From the 2nd CTE, query the min and max date values grouping by the key, value and grouping columns

**CODE**

```
CREATE TABLE SRC_TABLE (key1 integer, value1 integer, row_actual_from date, row_actual_to date);

INSERT INTO SRC_TABLE
VALUES
(19999923, 15, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'),
(19999923, 15, '2020-01-03', '2020-01-05'),
(19999923, 15, '2020-01-06', '2020-01-08'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-01-09', '2020-01-12'),
(19999923, 3434, '2020-01-13', '2020-01-15'),
(19999923, 15, '2020-01-16', '2020-01-20'),
(19999923, 15, '2020-01-21', '9999-12-31');


create or replace sequence seq_01 start = 1 increment = 1;
WITH T1 AS (
  SELECT KEY1, VALUE1, row_actual_from, row_actual_to
  ,CASE WHEN LAG(VALUE1,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY KEY1 ORDER BY row_actual_from ASC) = VALUE1 THEN null ELSE seq_01.nextval END AS CHK_MIN
  from SRC_TABLE
  order by row_actual_from
),
T2 AS (
  SELECT KEY1, VALUE1, row_actual_from, row_actual_to, CHK_MIN
  ,CASE WHEN CHK_MIN IS NULL THEN LAG(CHK_MIN,1,0) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY KEY1 ORDER BY row_actual_from ASC) ELSE CHK_MIN END AS CHK_MIN_GRP
  FROM T1
)
SELECT KEY1, VALUE1, MIN(ROW_ACTUAL_FROM), MAX(ROW_ACTUAL_TO)
FROM T2
GROUP BY KEY1, VALUE1, CHK_MIN_GRP
;
```

**RESULT**

```
KEY1        VALUE1      MIN(ROW_ACTUAL_FROM)    MAX(ROW_ACTUAL_TO)
19999923        15      2020-01-01              2020-01-08
19999923        3434    2020-01-09              2020-01-15
19999923        15      2020-01-16              9999-12-31
```